# Playing Movies From A Mounted Drive (Revue/GoogleTV)

Tags: android, media, google-tv, television

So I have been interested in programming for the Google TV for a while now, and have just started to get into it.

My first personal project is to create a simple media player and file browser, since the default media player is so awful. It works perfectly on the Android emulator (version 12), but when I install it into my Google Revue I find myself facing two major problems.

1) The player will always play the first movie alphabetically, no matter which movie file is chosen (all of the formats and paths are correct. URI loaded into setDataSource/setVideoPath)

2) Whenever I try to fast forward through a movie, it skips to the next movie alphabetically instead

I have used the mediaplayer and videoview examples from the android development website here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/index.html 
as well as the default action_view intent, but have the exact same problem with every single one. The movie will play 100% fine on the emulator, but have completely different defaults on the Google Revue.

Has anybody encountered this problem before or have any idea what I can do/where I can go to fix it?

*EDIT*

Here is my code to call the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myMediaPlayer.class);
intent.putExtra("PATH_ID", path);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here is my code to run the mediaPlayer. (pretty much an exact copy of the website's code)

```
public class myMediaPlayer extends Activity implements
    OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener,
    OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayerDemo";
private int mVideoWidth;
private int mVideoHeight;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private SurfaceView mPreview;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private String path;
private String extras;

private boolean mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
private boolean mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;

/**
 * 
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer);
    mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    holder = mPreview.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    extras = getIntent().getExtras().getString("PATH_ID");;

}

private void playVideo(String filePath) {
    doCleanUp();
    try {


        path = filePath;
        // Create a new media player and set the listeners
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);

}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
}

public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
    if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height + ")");
        return;
    }
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
    mVideoWidth = width;
    mVideoHeight = height;
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");

}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
}


public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
    playVideo(extras);


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

private void doCleanUp() {
    mVideoWidth = 0;
    mVideoHeight = 0;
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
}

private void startVideoPlayback() {
    Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
    holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

}

As an alternative, I tried just using the default player like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(aDirectory.getAbsolutePath())), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

But it always plays the first video alphabetically in the folder instead of the one selected

Comment: please add your code here...only the part which sets source of and starts the MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

regarding fast forwarding, check out: https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_media_keys

for the first question, you may find https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_displayguide#NavigationFocus helpful.